# How do I route all traffic on a machine over an openvpn server while the machine itself runs an openvpn server?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn

#### Advanced info

```
Machines involved:
A := vpn server inet 10.9.0.1 peer 10.9.0.2 tun0
B := vpn server inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.9.0.2 tun2
     vpn client inet 10.9.0.6 peer 10.9.0.5 tun1
C := vpn client inet 10.8.0.6 peer 10.9.0.5 tun0
```

#### Description

There are three machines. Machine B runs both an openvpn server and client. Now I when machine A pushes `redirect-gateway def1` to machine B, then machine C can't connect to the openvpn-server on machine B obviously, because the vpn-server reply packets are routed over to machine A, due to the `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.5, 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.5` routes.
Now I need policy routing to route the packets over machine's B WAN gateway.

#### Failed attempt 1

I tried to mark the packets that are sent from the vpn server with:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 1194 -j MARK --set-xmark 14
ip route add table 14 default via WAN_IP
ip rule add fwmark 14 table 14
```

But they are still routed over to machine A, which I could observe with `tcpdump -i tun1` on machine B and `tcpdump -i tun0` on machine A.

```
**machine B**
eth0:
22:22:33.734511 IP machine_C_IP.54089 > machine_B_IP.1194: UDP, length 86
tun1:
22:32:42.713371 IP 10.9.0.6.1194 > machine_C_IP.34514: UDP, length 94

**machine A**
tun0:
20:47:47.769628 IP machine_A_IP.openvpn > machine_C_IP.40287: UDP, length 94
```

#### Failed attempt 2

I also tried to mark packets by the owner of the openvpn process.
I added to openvpn@.service `Group = vpnserver` and then:

iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner vpnserver -j MARK --set-xmark 14 
    ip route add table 14 default via WAN_GATEWAY
    ip rule add fwmark 14 table 14

But packets are still routed over to machine A.

#### Working attempt

Following works, but it's something I want to avoid using, because it's not convenient, because I would have to add routes for every client by its IP. Some clients have also dynamic IPs, thus I would have to use a script to retrieve the right IP by a domain name.

```
ip route add table 14 default via WAN_IP
ip rule add to machine_C_IP table 14
```

#### Abstract

Maybe the marked packets fail being routed rightly, because the iptables' OUTPUT chain applies after the actual routing?
Or do I miss something while marking the packets? Is there any other way to route the outgoing vpn server packets to my WAN gateway?

#### Current state

Routes

```
default via WAN_GATEWAY dev eth0  table 42 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.5 dev tun1 
default via WAN_GATEWAY dev eth0 onlink 
10.1.1.0/24 dev veth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.2 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
10.9.0.0/24 via 10.9.0.5 dev tun1 
10.9.0.5 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.9.0.6 
WAN_SUBNET/26 via WAN_GATEWAY dev eth0 
WAN_SUBNET/26 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src WAN_IP 
MACHINE_A_IP via WAN_GATEWAY dev eth0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.9.0.5 dev tun1
```

IP rules

```
0:      from all lookup local 
32760:  from all fwmark 0xe lookup 42 
32761:  from all fwmark 0xa lookup 42 
32764:  from all to WAN_IP lookup 42 
32765:  from WAN_IP lookup 42 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: What kind of routing do you require for the client running the server? Only routing from its clients to the other vpn?

Comment: Machine B should route packets from 10.8.0.0/24 back over the WAN gateway to its clients directly and not over the other vpn server on machine A (10.9.0.1). Machine's B vpn client connects also directly to machine's A vpn server and machine's C vpn client connects directly to machine's B vpn server.

Comment: It's the same scenario that you explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391368/108542 , just that machine B now also runs an openvpn-server, not just vpn client. Again only outgoing traffic is routed over machine's A vpn server, but now with the exception for outgoing packets of the newly added vpn server of machine B. which I could only accomplish with `ip rule add to machine_C_IP table 14`. Didn't find a more clever way yet.

Comment: In short, routes you want on *B*: **from C forward to WAN** and **from B to A, except openvpn**? Also, why you using `--set-xmark` (and not `--set-mark`), and did you flush the routing caches after adding the routing rules?

Comment: Good question - I noticed I actually used `--set-mark`, but when looking at `iptables-save -t` it shows it as `--set-xmark`, iptables translates that probably to xmark. To your first question: Yes to **from B to A, except openvpn-server of B**. I think **from C forward to WAN** is not necessary because traffic that comes from C to B is routed rightly already, because C connects to the socket  `machine_B_WAN_IP:1194`. In `journalctl -u openvpn@server` I can also see machine C trying to connect, but it fails with `TLS Error: TLS handshake failed` :-)

Comment: I've actually never tried this, but if you interested: (1) Configure your OpenVPN instances to share the same primary group (create a group openvpn). Create iptables rule to match that group `iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid openvpn -j MARK --mark 42`. (2) Use a routing rule like before to use a separate WAN routing table for marked traffic (`ip rule add ...` like before). Now you should be able to connect with client on C. (3) `ip rule add iff tun2 table 42`.

Comment: Tried your suggestions, `ip rule add iff tun2 table 42` and `--gid-owner openvpn` but the client can't connect and I see the packets still running over tun1. Not sure why it's not working, maybe because the routing decision is already done before the iptables' OUTPUT chain. See: http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png I think I will try later to put either the vpn client or the vpn server inside a netns namespace, so that I don't have them clash in the root namespace. That might be another promising attempt :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65615/discussion-between-sebasth-and-fremon).

Answer (score 1):

Building on a previous answer in the thread, this is how I was able to solve the issue on my Ubuntu 17.10 (artful) computer running OpenVPN 2.4.3.

## 1) Disable reverse path filtering

We need to [change unicast reverse path forwarding](https://jamielinux.com/blog/bypass-openvpn-for-a-specific-unix-user/) to loose mode (`rp_filter=2`) instead of strict mode (`rp_filter=1`). In strict mode, an incoming packet must be received on the same network interface that would be used to forward the return packet.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.<if>.rp_filter=2
```

Where `<if>` is the physical ethernet interface the computer uses to connect to the router. In my case, the command looked like this: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.rp_filter=2`. To read the kernel parameter, use `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.<if>.rp_filter`.

To make the change persistent after a reboot, add or change this line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.<if>.rp_filter=2
```

## 2) Set OpenVPN server to mark encrypted packets

In the server `.conf` file, add:

```
mark <value>
```

Where `<value>` is an arbitrarely unique value for marking the packets. This will allow rerouting the packets encrypted by the OpenVPN server. I used `mark 9`.

Restart the OpenVPN server.

## 3) Reroute marked packets to the router with a new ip rule and ip route

```
ip rule add fwmark <value> table <N>
ip route add default via <router> table <N>
```

Where `<N>` is an arbitrarely unique number for the routing table and `<router>` is the router IP address in my LAN. In other words, I executed these commands: `ip rule add fwmark 9 table 42` and `ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 table 42`.

Making these changes persistent after reboot is more tricky, especially with Ubuntu 17.10 that uses the new netplan package for managing network connections instead of the traditionnal `/etc/network/interfaces` file. For lack of a better solution, I added a series of commands in the OpenVPN systemd service file. This will create the ip rule and route before the OpenVPN is started: `ExecStartPre=-/sbin/ip rule add fwmark 9 table 42` and `ExecStartPre=-/sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.8.1 table 42`. I use the minus `-` sign before the command path to make sure the server will start even if the command fails (in case the rule or route already exists), see the [systemd.service man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) for more information.

**Tip**: I run the OpenVPN server as a systemd service on my computer, the best way to troubleshoot this issue in my case was to increase the verbosity of the OpenVPN server in the `.conf` file to `6`, and then to use `journalctl -fu openvpn-server@<conf_file_name>.service` to see if the connection could be established. If reverse path filtering is not disabled, you may not even see any activity when the clients try to connect. After setting the `rp_filter` to `2` (step 1), I could see some activity, but the TLS handshake would fail. Once I managed to reroute the OpenVPN packets to the router (step 2-3), my clients were able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it fails

**Failed attempt 1** and **Failed attempt 2** don't work, because the iptables' chain runs after the routing decision, see the iptables' diagramm http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png.

Besides that, **Failed attempt 2** uses a wrong approach to set the User/Group of the vpn server instance. You need to specify the user or group in /etc/openvpn/server.conf and not in the systemd unit file. I.e.:

1. Create the user or group `adduser vpnserver`
2. Then add user or group to /etc/openvpn/server.conf
   `user vpnserver`
3. Verify the vpn server process runs as that user/group with `ps -A o pid,cmd,user,group|grep vpn`

#### Solution

You can mark packets of local processes only if the processes set a **socket option**. OpenVPN supports that:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage

You can mark a packet with the option `--mark value` in /etc/openvpn/server.conf and then use `ip rule add fwmark value table 42` with `ip routes default via WAN_GATEWAY table 42`.

Machine C can then connect to machine's B vpn server.

#### Alternative

Alternatively you could use netns namespaces for the vpn server and client and then make use of iptables' chains.

Comment: The statement "the iptables' chain runs after the routing decision" is wrong, obviously wrong. Even the diagram shows two points with routing decisions. Probably because you can use the output device in `iptables` rules. But the diagram is wrong. You can do DNAT in the nat OUTPUT chain and obviously the routing decision cannot be made before the target address is known.